# What does quoted-pair = "\" ( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / obs-text ) means in this RFC?

Tags: http, rust, ascii, rfc

On https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6 it says:

> The backslash octet ("\") can be used as a single-octet quoting
> mechanism within quoted-string and comment constructs.  Recipients
> that process the value of a quoted-string MUST handle a quoted-pair
> as if it were replaced by the octet following the backslash.

```
 quoted-pair    = "\" ( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / obs-text )
```

Does that mean that a quoted-pair can be `\`  or `\htab` or `hvchar` or `\obs-text`? I think you understand what I mean. Is the parenthesis above distribuing over the options inside of it?

So a quoted-pair can be any of these things:

```
 "\" HTAB
 "\" SP
 "\" VCHAR
 "\" obs-text
```

?

Because I've seen a code that does this:

```
pub fn is_quoting(c: u8) -> bool {
    b"\t ".contains(&c) || is_vchar(c) || is_obs_text(c)
}
```

The way this code is written, it interprets as if `quoted-pair` could be any of these:

```
HTAB

SP

VCHAR

obs-text
```

Comment: Your code sample is correct for matching the character *after* the backslash. The backslash is presumably consumed before that function is called.

Comment: @hobbs so I'm correct to interpret as `\` and `htab` OR `\` and `sp` OR `\` and `vchar` OR `\` and obs-text?